# Is it possible to configure the cloud function trigger be a on a folder level for GCS bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

For example, imagine we have the following:

gs://a_bucket/a_folder
Instead of setting trigger at gs://a_bucket when deploying, I need to set it at the folder level i.e. --trigger-bucket gs://a_bucket/a_folder/.

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible. Try to create the Cloud Function from the Google Cloud Console. When choosing the bucket from the buckets list, you will realize that the folders and files are grayed out. Which means that you can't pick a folder for the trigger. You can only choose the bucket.

As a workaround, you can check every new file that is being uploaded to the bucket and get the path. It will indicate in which folder it was uploaded and you can check the folder with an `if statement` and perform actions there.

I did a little bit of coding myself and you can see my [example code in GitHub](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Cloud%20Functions/get_filePath_fileName_CloudStorageTrigger_python.py). The main function is being triggered by the event and then it uses two extra functions to retrieve the file's path and the file's name.

Comment: Ya agreed with your answer! Could not find it till now

Comment: The situation didn't change? This is just terrible, because the cloud function will trigger more than necessary. I guess it's better to trigger the cloud function manually with https on this case.

Comment: I've added an answer into the duplicate question here, so others might find this useful